# How do I get system uptime in Mono on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, portability, uptime

My code on Windows used P/Invoke to call `GetTickCount64()` from kernel32.dll This doesn't work under Mono on Ubuntu Server 14 - I get `EntryPointNotFoundException`.

There's [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/972189/57428) using `PerformanceCounter`. It works on Windows but when I use it on Linux with counter name/category set to `System`/`System Up Time` it yields zero timespans all the time. So it doesn't work too.

`Environment.Tickount` works the same as on Windows but it overflows every 47 days and this can get confusing results for my usecase, so I'd prefer a 64-bit counter.

How do I get system uptime in C# code running with Mono on Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Use native Linux way then, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540627/what-api-do-i-call-to-get-the-system-uptime

Comment: @LexLi How do I start with doing that in C# code?

Comment: Google how to do PInvoke on Mono. No much difference compared to what you do on Windows.

Comment: @LexLi That sounds too hard. I tried to `File.ReadAllText("/proc/uptime")` as outlined in one of the answers and it works just fine. Thank you.

Comment: Then post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

[User Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) linked to this [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1540627/57428) for C code.

Among the answers is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1540635/57428) which suggets reading from `/proc/uptime`. This is just great for C# code - it can use `File.ReadAllText()` and then parse the resulting string.

```
var uptimeText = File.ReadAllText( "/proc/uptime" );
// Now split the string to extract the first component,
// parse it as double and use TimeSpan.FromSeconds()
```