# How to get time differences (milliseconds) independent of system time?

Tags: c++, linux

I need to calculate time difference in milliseconds on Linux (Ubuntu 14).

It needs to be independent from system time because the application may change it during the execution (it sets system time according to the data received from GPS).

I've checked the [clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) function and it doesn't work for us because it returns the processor time consumed by the program and we need the real time.

The sysinfo (as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540627/what-api-do-i-call-to-get-the-system-uptime)) return seconds since boot and, again, we need milliseconds.

And reading from /proc/uptime (as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095439/how-do-i-get-system-up-time-in-milliseconds-in-c)) seem to be slow according to our tests (considering we want milliseconds and this function is called repeatedly).

We can use C++11, but I think std::chrono is related to system time also (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there any other method to accomplish this?

---

Our Performance Test (for /proc/uptime comparison), 1 million of repeated calls:

## gettimeofday:

(not what we need since it depends on the system time)

```
#include <sys/time.h>

unsigned int GetMs(){
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    timeval ts;
    gettimeofday(&ts,0);
    static long long inici = 0;
    if (inici==0){
        inici = ts.tv_sec;
    }
    ts.tv_sec -= inici;
    ret = (ts.tv_sec*1000 + (ts.tv_usec/1000));
    return ret;
}
```

## clock:

(not valid, returns ticks used by the application, not real time)

```
#include <time.h>
unsigned int GetMs(){
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();
    ret = t / 1000;
    return ret;
}
```

## uptime:

```
#include <fstream>
unsigned int GetMs(){
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    double uptime_seconds;
    if (std::ifstream("/proc/uptime", std::ios::in) >> uptime_seconds) {
        ret = (int) (1000 * uptime_seconds);
    }
}
```

Results:

- gettimeofday: 31 milliseconds
- clock: 153 milliseconds
- uptime: 6005 milliseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The low-level system primitive that does what you want is [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) with the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` "clockid".

> **CLOCK_MONOTONIC**: Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some unspecified starting point. This clock is not affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system administrator manually changes the clock), but is affected by the incremental adjustments performed by adjtime(3) and NTP.

(Being "affected by the incremental adjustments performed by adjtime(3) and NTP" is almost certainly what you want.)

This function is declared in `<time.h>` and, with current versions of GNU libc, is accessible by default.  With older versions you may need to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to a value greater than or equal to `200809L` before including *any* system headers (not just before including `time.h`), and you may also need to link your program against `-lrt`.

`clock_gettime` returns a `struct timespec`, which can express differences of a single nanosecond; the actual precision is usually somewhat less, but you ought to be able to count on millisecond precision, especially if a program that "disciplines" the system clock (e.g. `ntpd`) is running.

Answer (score 9):

What you want is [std::chrono::steady_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock)

> Class `std::chrono::steady_clock` represents a monotonic clock. The time points of this clock cannot decrease as physical time moves forward. This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be time since last reboot), and is most suitable for measuring intervals.

If you need to support a C++98/03 environment you could also use [`boost:steady_clock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.system_clocks_hpp.steady_clock)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works perfectly and is not dependant to system clock, which fulfills my requirements. However, I'm accepting @zwol's answer for being faster according to my tests. On my embedded device, 1000000 repeated calls, std::chrono::steady_clock took 3523 ms and clock_gettime with CLOCK_MONOTONIC took 2184 ms.

Comment: @PauGuillamon No problem.  Glad to help.